# Rails ModelSweeper.instance expires nothing

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sweeper

Rails 3.2.8, ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]

When I use a sweeper inside another sweeper with `instance` method, the sweeper function (like  `after_update`) is executed (I did a log and is executed) but expires nothing in my project. (or Task)

My code is the next:

```
class WorkSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  # ...
  def after_update(work)
    expire work, "/works/index"
    expire work, "/tasks/#{work.task_id}/works/index"

    expire work, "/works/#{work.id}/show"

    TaskSweeper.instance.after_update work.task
  end
  # ...
end

class TaskSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  # ...
  def after_update(task)
    expire task, "/tasks/index"
    expire task, "/milestones/#{task.target_id}/tasks/index"
    expire task, "/tasks/#{task.target_id}/tasks/index"
    expire task, "/projects/#{task.target_id}/tasks/index"

    expire task, "/tasks/#{task.id}/show"

    MilestoneSweeper.instance.after_update task.target if task.target.class == Milestone
  end
  # ...
end

class MilestoneSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  # ...
  def after_update(milestone)
    expire milestone, "/milestones/index"
    expire milestone, "/projects/#{milestone.project_id}/milestones/index"

    expire milestone, "/milestones/#{milestone.id}/show"

    ProjectSweeper.instance.after_update milestone.project
  end
  # ...
end

class ProjectSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  # ...
  def after_update(project)
    expire project, "/projects/index"
    expire project, "/companies/#{project.company_id}/projects/index"

    expire project, "/projects/#{project.id}/show"
  end
  # ...
end
```

Note: `expire` is the next function

```
def scope(project)
  project.creator.try(:creator_id) || project.creator_id
end

def expire(model, url)
  expire_fragment("#{scope model}#{url}")
end
```

I need to execute each expire manually in each sweeper, like:

```
class WorkSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  # ...
  def after_update(work)
    expire work, "/works/index"
    expire work, "/tasks/#{work.task_id}/works/index"

    expire work, "/works/#{work.id}/show"

    expire project, "/projects/index"
    expire project, "/companies/#{project.company_id}/projects/index"

    expire project, "/projects/#{project.id}/show"
  end
  # ...
end
```

In this case, works, but it is not the best, I have lots of model and lots of sweepers.

What is wrong? Is there another way to do the same?.

Thanks.

**Solved**

Answer here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8096